# Chrome settings/password shortcut with Autohotkey

Tags: google-chrome, autohotkey

I'm trying to do a shortcut with autohotkey (I am a noob with it) to go to chrome://settings/password/ when i'm on chrome.

The *Run* command works only for the URL, something like:

```
Run, http://stackoverflow.com
```

So I tried this script, but it's rough to me:

```
;myScript:

#IfWinActive, ahk_class Chrome_WidgetWin_1
    ^q::Send, ^t chrome://settings/passwords/ {enter}
#IfWinActive
```

There are some ways to do it better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it step by step:

```
;myScript:

#IfWinActive, ahk_class Chrome_WidgetWin_1

    ^q::
    Send, ^t
    Sleep 500
    ; replace "title" with the exact title of the new window (tab)
    ; WinWait, title
    ; IfWinNotActive, title, ,WinActivate, title
    ; WinWaitActive, title
   SendInput, chrome://settings/  ; SendInput is faster in sending text
    Sleep 500
    Send, {enter}
    Sleep 500
    ; replace "title" with the exact title of the new window (tab)
    ; WinWait, title
    ; IfWinNotActive, title, ,WinActivate, title
    ; WinWaitActive, title
    Send, {Tab 2}
    Sleep 500
    Send, {enter}
    return

#IfWinActive
```

Comment: ok, many thanks, it works! But I don't get the *Send, {Tab 2}* command because it seems that it only reloads the page.

Comment: Try as many tabs as necessary or use Send, {Tab} if it focuses the link.

Answer (score 0):

I usually incorporate a few loops to account for delays across old hardware, and just break out when the conditions are met.

You can trigger the Passwords box in Chrome with the below, currently bound to F4.

```
F4::
{
    WinActivate, ahk_class Chrome_WidgetWin_1
    Loop {
        IfWinActive, ahk_class Chrome_WidgetWin_1
        {
            break
        }
        }
    Send, ^t
    Loop {
        IfWinActive, New Tab - Google Chrome
        {
            break
        }
        }
    Send, chrome://settings/passwords{enter}
}
return
```